# StreamReader to read a line from text file and pick a word that matches the criteria

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm writing a a program  in c# to read through the text file using stream reader.
 There is a line , which says "The data set WORK.Test has 0 observations and 5 variables".
The stream reader has to read through this line, and get into an "if else loop" based on the number of Observations.
. How i can make the stream reader pick on 0 or not observations.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@FilePath);
List<String> Spec = new List<String>();
while (file.EndOfStream != true)
{
    string s = file.ReadLine();
    Match m = Regex.Match(s, "WORK.Test has");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        // Find the number of observations  
        // and send an email if there are more than 0 observations.
    }
}
```

Comment: Post sample of text file with a few repetitions of each item.  It is nearly impossible to parse a text file from a vague description.  Been parsing text files for over 40 years and each text file parsing is different from all the others.  you have to look for patterns in the input and you must be able to distinguish the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your `Regex`.

In `C#` `Regex` class, whatever you put inside `( )` will be captured into a group item. So assuming your input sting looks like what you've specified except for the numbers, you can capture observations and variables by using `\d+`.

`\d` - Searches for a digit.

`\d+` - Searches for one or more digits.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("File.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();
            var match = Regex.Match(line, @"WORK.Test has (\d+) observations and (\d+) variables");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out int observations);
                int.TryParse(match.Groups[2].Value, out int variables);
                // Send EMail etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i tried this way of reading the log file , and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. In your example, you want to get only the number between "has" and "obervations"? Why do you not use Regex? 
Btw the one you provided is wrong as "." matches anything. You rather should try `@"WORK\.Test has (.*) observations"`